# How to write tiff image without alpha channel using RMagick

Tags: tesseract, rmagick, libtiff

I'm trying to write a TIFF image with RMagick that tesseract can process. Tesseract objects if bits per pixel is > 32 or samples per pixel is other than 1, 3 or 4.

With the defaults, `Image.write` generates 3 (RGB) samples plus 1 alpha channel at 16-bits per sample for a total of 64 bits per pixel, violating the first constraint.

If I set the colorspace to `GRAYColorspace` as follows, it still outputs the alpha channel, giving two samples per pixel, violating the second constraint.

```
Image.write('image.tif) {self.colorspace = GRAYColorspace}
```

Per the [RMagick documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/info.html), the alpha channel is ignored on method operations unless specified, but even if I do `self.channel(GREYChannel)`, the alpha channel is still output.

I know I can run `convert` on the file afterwards, but I'd like to find a solution that avoids that.

Here is the `tiffinfo` output for the file currently generated:

TIFF Directory at offset 0x9c48 (40008)

```
  Image Width: 100 Image Length: 100
  Bits/Sample: 16
  Compression Scheme: None
  Photometric Interpretation: min-is-black
  Extra Samples: 1<unassoc-alpha>
  FillOrder: msb-to-lsb
  Orientation: row 0 top, col 0 lhs
  Samples/Pixel: 2
  Rows/Strip: 20
  Planar Configuration: single image plane
  Page Number: 0-1
  DocumentName: image-gray-colorspace.tif
  White Point: 0.3127-0.329
  PrimaryChromaticities: 0.640000,0.330000,0.300000,0.600000,0.150000,0.060000
```